# How does this recursive function return the correct answer?

Tags: c, function, recursion, definition

I wanted to know how this function returns 4 which is the correct answer, when it resets the `res` variable every time the function calls itself.
`num = 2367319`

```
int func(int num)
{
    int res = 0;
    if (num > 0)
        res = (num % 10 % 3 == 0 ? 1 : 0) + func(num / 10);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: `res` is known as a local variable so has multiple instances, one per function call. I.e. `res` is not "reset"

Comment: Though `num % 10 % 3 == 0 ` works fine, I'd use more parentheses to make it perfectly clear (so you don't need to consult a precedence and associativity chart): `((num % 10) % 3) == 0 `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`res` isn't "reset". Rather a new local variable named `res` is created for each recursive call.

I suggest you add some `printf()` statements in order to see how this function works.

Comment: everytime the func calles itself it sets res = 0; that what i dont understand. it resets res every call.

Comment: @noornapso Every time the func calls itself, **it creates a new variable named `res`** that is initialized to `0`. Nothing is "reset".

Answer (score 0):

`res` equals the number of digits divisible with 3. It will always get a proper value, as long as num is still greater than 0.

Comment: I think you mean "the number of digits divisible by three", correct?

Answer (score 0):

For starters the declaration and the implementation of the function is bad.

The function parameter has the type `int`. So the user can supply a negative number and will await how many digits of the number are divisible by 3. However the function returns 0. A question arises: and what to do with negative numbers? To write one more function?

The second problem is that the function is unable to process integer numbers of types `long int` and `long long int`. Again do we need to write separate functions for these signed integer types?

The function uses an redundant variable res.

It can be declared and implemented the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below..

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int func( long long int n )
{
    const long long int Base = 10;

    return n == 0 ? 0 : ( n % Base % 3 == 0 ) + func( n / Base );  
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%d : %u\n", 2367319, func( 2367319 ) );
    printf( "%d : %u\n", -2367319, func( -2367319 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2367319 : 4
-2367319 : 4
```

How does the function works?

If the n is equal to 0 then the function returns 0.

```
    return n == 0 ? 0 : ( n % Base % 3 == 0 ) + func( n / Base );  
           ^^^^^^   ^^
```

Otherwise if the last digit `n % Base` (the remainder of division by 10) of the number is divisible by `3` then this expression

```
    return n == 0 ? 0 : ( n % Base % 3 == 0 ) + func( n / Base );  
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

yields `1` (true). Otherwise it yields `0`. So the function counts the number of digits divisible by `3` in such a way recutsively.

For example let's consider the number `2367319`.

The expression `2367319 % 10` yields the digit `9`. `9 % 3` (`2367319 % 10 % 3`) is equal to 0. So the expression

```
2367319 % 10 % 3 == 0
```

yields `1`.

Now the function calls itself with the number `2367319 / 10` that is with the number `236731`. And the operation with the last digit of this new number is repeated. In this case the expression

```
236731 % 10 % 3 == 0
```

evaluates to `0` (false).

And so on. All results of the function calls are accumulated and returned.

In fact you will have

```
(2367319 % 10 % 3 == 0) + (236731 % 10 % 3 == 0) + (23673 % 10 % 3 == 0) +...+ 0

         1              +         0              +        1              +...+ 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, when function is called all it's local variables are created on `stack`(i.e stack pointer incremented by amount of local variables used). Upon function exit stack pointer is decremented by same amount.

Consider below example, function `foo()` with some bytes of local variables calling a `bar()` with some other bytes of local variable. (For simplistic purpose I have excluded the function return  address from stack)

```
 /*stack growth in this direction ---->*/


 foo()-------+
             |
    /*foo code execution */
             | 
           bar()----------+
                          |
                  /* bar() Code execution */
                          | 
             +------------+
             |
|------------+
```

As functions is called stack is expanded and shrinks upon  function exit.

In case of recursive function `bar()` happens to be `foo()` again and again. But new stack location is allocated for every function call.

And hence in your case `res` is being set to zero at different stack location even though it appears to be same variable name.